# ASP.NET Web Forms Multiple conditions with IIF EVAL

Tags: asp.net

I have this div with a IIF(Eval()) statement:

```
<div id="Div1" style="text-align: center;" runat="server" 
     visible='<%# IIF(Eval("rmtype_id")=2,"false","true") %>'>
    Content here  
</div>
```

My question is - is it possible to put OR or AND operators in the IIF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. ([IF syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx))

```
IIf(a > 2 And b > 3, "True", "False")
```

OR

```
If(a > 2 And b > 3, "True", "False")
```

Comment: Doh! I was using || and && and never thought about OR and AND. Thanks @AVD.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the first argument can be any expression that evaluates to a boolean.

Something like this is perfectly valid:

```
IIF(Eval("rmtype_id") = 2 Or Eval("rmtype_id") > 10, "false", "true")
```

Check out the [IIf function docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more info.